# First? Single? Or Default?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I've searched StackOverflow but still cannot understand the correct syntax to use Single, First (or default) queries.

I'm willing to make a query to catch first the translation in specific language. If there is no such translation on the db, get the first one in English.

Here is what I got so far:

```
locale = "ja-jp";

var items = from c in db.Contents.Include("Translation")
            where c.RegionalInfo.Any(x => x.RegionId == locale)
            select c;
```

**Edit**
Obs.: items is an IEnumerable

Comment: your desired results are not clear to me.  Can you put some context in this?

Comment: One Content has many translations, one translation can have only one associated Content. I need a list of Contents with the first translation available, preferred localized. If there is no localized translation, use english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your explanation, it sounds like you want the value if found, and if not found to use the english translation. Consider the following:

```
locale = "ja-jp"; 

var itens = from c in db.Contents.Include("Translation") 
            where c.RegionalInfo.Any(x => x.RegionId == locale) ||
                  c.RegionalInfo.Any(x => x.RegionId == "en")
            order by (c.RegionalInfo.RegionId == "en", "zzzz", c.RegionalInfo.RegionId) 
            select c; 
var foundItem = items.FirstOrDefault();
if (foundItem != null)
{ ... }
```

This finds the reocrds that match your locale and the english one and then sorts the results by the regionId placing the found english item at the end of the list and then takes the first record (if found). Note: I didn't test this implementation, so make sure to check the orderby parameter to make sure it works as designed.

Comment: I will try something like this. But I need to return an IEnumerable, not a single element. And c.RegionalInfo.RegionId is not available here. "RegionalInfo" is an navigation property. Thanks anyway, Jim.

Answer (score 4):

Try something like this.

```
var item = (from c in db.Contents.Include("Translation")
        where c.RegionalInfo.Any(x => x.RegionId == locale)
        select c).FirstOrDefault();
if (item != null)
   ...
```

Answer (score 3):

Although operations like `Select`, `Where`, etc can be translated into query syntax, quite a few extension methods can't. In this case, `First`, `Last`, `Single` (+ `XXXOrDefault`) operations can be performed using any enumerable but not with query syntax.

Because the compiler is smart enough to translate the query into an associated result of an `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<t>`, you can simply wrap your query in parenthesis and then call the methods:

```
var item = (from c in dbo.Contents.Include("Translation")
            where c.RegionInfo.Any(x => x.RegionId == locale)
            select c).FirstOrDefault();
```

... etc.

Comment: i personally find this clumsy in practice and prefer `var query = ...; var result = query.Single();` style, so there is a clear separation between query and enumeration.

Comment: @asawyer - for pure readability, certainly, it makes sense to break the operations down so it is clear what is going on... but in reality, the compiler doesn't care.

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you prefer <strike>"non-Linq"</strike> method syntax, you can do something like this:

```
var item = dbo.Contents.Include("Translation").FirstOrDefault(m => m.RegionInfo.Any(n => n.RegionId == locale));
```

Comment: Normally this is called expression syntax (versus query syntax).

Comment: Ok, despite Expression syntax or query syntax, how it will know that "Default" is "english"? Will it return the first it finds?

Comment: @programad: The default is null for any reference type, zero for any numeric type, false for Boolean. Since a string is a reference type, you'll get null.

Comment: OK, now I see that "XXXOrDefault" is not what I thought It was. It is all about T, not about my stuff on the db. I need to do something like Jim Wooley told me to do. Will try an aproach like that.

Comment: Hey, John. Is this true? Check out the "expression syntax" examples on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447.aspx

Comment: It looks like the actual terms are "Query Syntax" and "Method Syntax"? Apologies for being nerdily taxonomic. :]

Comment: @weirdlover I stand corrected, thank you. It is indeed method syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DefaultIfEmpty` extension to set a default value for an empty sequence.